# Why was Bastila Shan in orbit of Taris?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

Bastila Shan was intercepted by Sith forces in orbit of Taris and the crew evacuated from the Endar Spire to the planet. While KotOR's protagonist is on the planet, he doesn't do much more than

> save Bastila and run from Taris

But Taris was already controlled by Sith forces, so why did Bastila go here? Is there any information about that?

Comment: Are you sure Taris was controlled by the Sith? I got the impression that it was, at best, neutral. With the Sith bombardment turning it into rubble and all...

Comment: @Kakturus It was patrolled by Sith forces (you even had to steal their uniforms) and there was a Sith base, so it doesn't look neutral.

Comment: Hm. Then the decision to bombard the whole planet was even more stupid than I remembered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is mentioned in-game, but during the promotion of the sequel KotoR II, Lucasarts wrote a series of articles giving background info on the era & setting. Among it was mention of the Endar Spire's original mission: to link up with a larger Jedi battle fleet
set to engage the Sith's fleet over Taris, but an interdiction field dropped them out of hyperspace straight into an ambush, which is where the game starts off.

I'd give you a more solid citation, but getting hold of the original article is a bit tricky since the offical webpage is long defunct and was flash heavy, so the wayback machine is a little unreliable.

Comment: some info here; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Taris/Legends

Comment: @NKCampbell if you want to expand it into full answer (or you Kris include it in your answer) then I'll gladly accept it, as description from link anwers question. If not, I'll create answer :)

Comment: all yours @Elas

Comment: I was aware of the wookipedia article, but didn't cite it because it's a secondary source at best, and as I said the primary source is tricky to access.